# Who listens to the port

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp

I have a conflict between the mail server and one more service.

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w ': 25'
```

Conclusion:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6 0 0 ::: 25 ::: * LISTEN -
The problem is that I do not know who is listening on port 25. How can this be determined?
```

---

I fixed it:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
[sudo] password for eurvanov: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2967/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1445/teamviewerd    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      583/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      709/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7935/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      955/tor             
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2967/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45577           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2967/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      709/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      7935/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::10012                :::*                    LISTEN      2199/docker-proxy
```

Comment: Hi, what OS it's ? as on an Windows OS netstat return a PID, which if your process ID (that is findable in taskmgr)

Comment: os: ubuntu18.04

Comment: To cite from the output of netstat: *"Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, __you would have to be root to see it all__"*. This clearly says what you need to do: __run netstat as root__.

Comment: Yes, i was found it. This is `postfix` process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see processes in deprecated `netstat` (or current `ss`) output if you are not root and aren't the process owner.

To see the process information for all processes, you need to run it as root, e.g. with `sudo`. For example:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ': 25'
```